# How perform jQuery or JS function when swf start play?

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<object width="500" height="500" id="ItemEditAnimationObject" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
        <param value="./Flash/1380312474.swf" name="movie">
        <param value="" name="wmode">
        <param value="false" name="loop">
        <param value="true" name="play"> 
        <param value="high" name="quality">
        <param value="#F0F8FF" name="bgcolor">
        <param value="./Sound/1380312474.wav" name="movie">

        <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object width="500" height="500" id="ItemEditAnimationObject" data="./Flash/1380312474.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param value="" name="wmode">
        <param value="false" name="loop">
        <param value="true" name="play"> 
        <param value="high" name="quality">
        <param value="#F0F8FF" name="bgcolor">
        <param value="./Sound/1380312474.wav" name="movie">

        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->

      </object>
```

Jquery (or JS):

```
function Start(){
alert('start');
}
```

How perform function `Start` when object start play?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control to actionscript / flex code of that player you can call your javascript function using `ExternternalInterface.Call("Start");`

Comment: Does anything on HTML side of page where you have embeded swf changes ? If so you can check that element . But otherwise there is no other way